# Can't change data members' values of member object

Tags: c++, oop, composition

In this sample program:

- I created a **class A** with a object member of class B
- **Class B** contains data member **x** with a setter and a getter
- Constructor of **Class B** initialize data member **x** with the **value 5**
- **Class A** contains member function **func ()** to set the value of data member **x** of **class B** to value: **7**

Now the value of **x** before and after calling **func()** doesn't change to **7**, what is the problem?

**Here is my code:**

Class A header

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H
#include "B.h"

class A
{
public:
    B getB();
    void func ();

private:
    B obj;
};

#endif // A_H
```

Class A implementation

```
#include "A.h"

B A :: getB ()
{
    return obj;
}

void A :: func ()
{
    getB().setX (7);
}
```

Class B header

```
#ifndef B_H
#define B_H


class B
{
public:
    B ();
    int getX ();
    void setX (int);
private:
    int x;


};

#endif // B_H
```

Class B implementation

```
#include "B.h"

B :: B () : x(5)
{

}
void B :: setX (int x)
{
    this->x = x;
}
int B :: getX()
{
    return x;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    A instanceA;
    cout << instanceA.getB().getX() << "\n";
    instanceA.func();
    cout << instanceA.getB().getX();
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

5

5

Comment: You are returning by value, meaning you are returning a copy of `B` and modifying the copy. The original remains unchanged. Try returning by reference, `B& getB();`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is returning by value (a copy of `obj` and not `obj` itself):

```
B getB()
{
    return obj;
}
```

To return the variable itself, you should return a *reference* to it:

```
B& getB()
{
    return obj;
}
```